# Как установить флаги компилятор через cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake

столкнулся с проблемой, для компилирования программы надо указать gcc флаги `-I -L -l`. Так вот не получается установить данные флаги в cmake. Подскажите как правильно устанавливать данные флаги?

Проблема больше относиться к tensorflow.

[Tensorwlof Install C](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_c)

Внизу есть пункт о решении проблем с компиляцией. Проверил действительно оно решает данную проблему. Но только через командную строку

```
gcc -I /opt/tensorflow/include -L /opt/tensorflow/lib tenso.c -l tensorflow
```

А так как у меня проект, то флаги нужно указать в cmake.

**Код из файла CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(tensorflow_example)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include_directories(/opt/tensorflow/include)
link_directories(/opt/tensorflow/lib)

target_link_libraries(tensorflow_example tensorflow)

add_executable(tensorflow_example main.cpp)
```

Генерирует вот такую ошибку:

> /snap/clion/19/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /home/lev/CLionProjects/tensorflow/cmake-build-debug --target all -- -j 2
>   CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (target_link_libraries):
>     Cannot specify link libraries for target "tensorflow_example" which is not
>     built by this project.

Comment: а что это за флаги для gcc? Это не флаги прилинковки библиотек?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я не знаю, что эти флаги для gcc означают(почему то смутное сомнение, не флаги ли это линковки, а не компиляции). Я вам отвечу на вопрос об общем подходе добавления **флагов компиляции**, так как вы об этом спрашиваете. 
Давайте добавим наши флаги компиляции в некую константу

```
SET(MYCOMPILE_FLAGS "-l -L -l")
```

Теперь мы может поступить одним из следующих способов:

1. Еще один подход появился с версии Cmake 3.0.2. Можно использовать для этого специальную команду [target_compile_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_compile_options.html)

   ```
   target_compile_options(${ourtargetname} ${MYCOMPILE_FLAGS})
   ```

   Первым аргументом(${ourtargetname}) необходимо передать ваше имя сборки(target-а), при компиляции которой будут применены переданные флаги.
2. Добавить флаги компиляции в предопределенную переменную [CMAKE_C_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/envvar/CFLAGS.html?highlight=cmake_c_flags)(или в [CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/envvar/CXXFLAGS.html?highlight=cmake_cxx_flags), если у вас компиляции с++ исходников), которые содержать дефолтные флаги компиляции соответствующих компиляторов.

   ```
   SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${MYCOMPILE_FLAGS }")
   SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${MYCOMPILE_FLAGS }")
   ```

   Или можно добавить новые параметры в переменную через команду [LIST](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/list.html)(спасибо @Ixsci за дополнение)

   ```
   LIST(append CMAKE_C_FLAGS ${MYCOMPILE_FLAGS })
   LIST(append CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${MYCOMPILE_FLAGS })
   ```
3. Добавить флаги компиляции с помощью команды [add_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_definitions.html).

   ```
   add_definitions(${MYCOMPILE_FLAGS})
   ```

   Эта команда предназначена в первую очередь для добавления препроцессорных переменных при компиляции исходников, но передача флагов компиляции для компилятора также должна работать.

**Теперь ответ на вопрос(не знаю, если сообщество скажет предыдущий текст удалить, я его удалю)**

Чтобы установить дополнительный путь до заголовочных файлов, вы должны воспользоваться командой [include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html)

```
include_directories(/opt/tensorflow/include)
```

Чтобы добавить дополнительный путь для поиска библиотек линковщику, необходимо воспользоваться командой [link_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/link_directories.html)

```
link_directories(/opt/tensorflow/lib)
```

Чтобы прилинковать библиотеку *tensorflow* к цели(exe или dll), которая вероятно находиться в папке 
*/opt/tensorflow/lib*, нужно вызвать команду [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html)

```
target_link_libraries(${ourtargetname} tensorflow)
```

Первым аргументом(${ourtargetname}) необходимо передать ваше имя сборки(target-а)

*${ourtargetname}*- это название выходного файла, имя сборки. Это имя вы указываете первым параметром либо в команде `add_executable`(если собираете exe файл), либо в `add_library`(если собираете библиотеку). В вашем примере вы собираете exe файл, поэтому в CMakeLists ищите функцию `add_executable` и увидите в ней имя сборки в первом параметре.

Comment: Лучше 3-й пункт сделать первым, т.к. это всё таки рекомендованный путь. Есть ещё `add_compile_options`, ну и добавлять к списку лучше через `list(append var ${another_var})` а не выставлять через `set(var ${var} ${another_var})`.

Comment: Ну почему-то не один из вариантов не помог. Ну у меня больше проблема относиться к tensorflow. [Tensorwlof Install C](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_c) в низу есть пункт о решении проблем с компиляцией. Проверил действительно оно решет данную проблему. Но только через командную строку 

gcc -I /opt/tensorflow/include -L /opt/tensorflow/lib tenso.c -l tensorflow

А так как у меня проект, то флаги нужно указать в cmake

Comment: @ixSci, спасибо за замечание. У меня логика в том, что способ с флагами был долгим временем предпочитаемым способом, поэтому я его и добавил первым. Но на текущий момент вы правы, должен быть порядок другой

Comment: @LevBazdyrev, а это и не поможет, потому что это не флаги компиляции. :) Поэтому я вас и просил уточнить вопрос, что вы делаете этими флагами

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov при флаги -I я указываю путь к include файлам, при флаге -L путь к библиотеке а вот флаг -l я так и не понял что он делает.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov всё таки для меня остался неясным один вопрос ${ourtargetname} - откуда его взять? Или эта переменная храниться в самом CMake?

Comment: @LevBazdyrev, написал откуда взять.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov выложил код с файла CMakeLists.txt, он у меня генерирует ошибку. не могу понять почему.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77523/discussion-between-levbazdyrev-and-alexcei-shmakov).